# combinatorial equivalence of abstract simplicial complexes

Tags: simplicial-complexes, simplicial-categories

what is the most natural equivalence one defines on abstract simplicial complexes ? The definition is purely combinatorial of abstract SCs. It seems to me that the combinatorial equivalence is however not interesting because it leads to many topologically equivalent SCs. However, I wonder if the combinatorial invariants (say generalization of ones obtained from graphs ) of a SC are useful at all if we consider the topological equivalence.